# How to dynamicaly remove html elements for specific object depending on which button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am using a jsp and servlet.

Trying to use JQuery and ajax to delete the user details off the page for the user's button that as clicked. The list of users could have any amount. I am trying to set the id of the form and button to the user's id so it correctly deletes the user's elements.

The user object is not declared in the script and that is an error. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=user.getUserId()%>").click(function(){
        $("#").remove();
});
```

});
`

The code with the list of users sent by the servlet. I want to remove everything in the form including itself without refreshing the page. I already have the user being deleted from the database with the first hidden input below.

```
<%
    Object userObj = session.getAttribute("userList");
    List<User> userList = (List<User>) userObj;
    if (userList != null && userList.size() > 0) {
%>

<%
    for (User user : userList) {

%>      
<form action="Servlet" method="post" id="<%=user.getUserId()%>">
    <p><%= user.getUsername()%></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="removeUser" value=<%=user.getUserId()%> />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="removeUser" />
    <input id="<%=user.getUserId()%>" type="submit" value="Remove User" />
</form>
<%
        }
    }
%>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, might get you in the right direction

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/04/ajax-add-delete-sql-records-jquery-php

Comment: I just need to delete the html elements. This shows how to delete from a database.

Answer (score 0):

add a submit button at the end of ur form like `<input type="submit"  name="submitform" class="sub">` and then using jquery with a selector of your choice and click function remove form. `$('.sub').click(function () { $("form").remove();
}` 
or add a class to ur form and then use it as a selector to be more specific.

```
<form action="Servlet" method="post" id="<%=user.getUserId()%>" class="targetthisform">
$('.sub').click(function () { $(".targetthisform").remove();}
```

Comment: The form is in a for loop. There could be 10 forms on the page. This code only deletes the first one.

Comment: can you add a class to the form and target the class. this way the class is always true and fixed for all your forms that you want to target

Comment: Then all the forms would have the same class because of the for loop and this would not solve the problem.